# Determine the data type of a key with a map - Java

Tags: java, dictionary, types, key

I have a method with a map as a passed in parameter.  The key for the map will either be a Long or an Integer data type.

I am using the method `map.containsKey()` to check to see if a number being randomly generated as primitive type int is contained in the passed in map.

The problem occurs when the map's key is of type Long and `map.containsKey()` evaluates to false.  Even if the map contains that int key value in Long form.

However if I try and cast the int to a long, the map expecteing an Integer will now have the same error.

I was wondering if there is a way to get the data type of a Map's key and then cast the generated number to that type so I can then use the `map.containsKey()` method?

I understand and wish I could just use a long as the key value for both maps, however that is not within the requirements of the assignment.

Appreciate any help.

Here is the code and the fields I am using

```
private TreeMap<Integer, LabClass> classes;
private HashMap<Long, Member> members;

public long generateUniqueNumber(AbstractMap map, int low, int high)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
    int max = high - low + 1;

    if (map.size() < max)
    {
        do {
            number = rand.nextInt(max) + low;
        } while (map.containsKey(number) );
    }

    return number;
}
```

Comment: That's how `equals` is implemented - objects of different classes are rarely equal. Why not store everything as a `long` and cast to `long` before calling `get`?

Comment: Ok, I will try and post that.  I would love to have everything as type long, but the requirements are that one map be HashMap<Long, Object> and another be TreeMap<Integer, Object>

Comment: I posted the code as well as made some edits to the post to further elaborate.  Also took someones suggestions of edits and learned a few things about posting already.  Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Long as the key type and then there would be no need for casting. (Maybe you have a reason for not using Long as the key)

Comment: No, getting with an `int` would not work - look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Long.java#Long.equals%28java.lang.Object%29). You would still have to cast on `get`. The point is that you have a consistent cast - always to `long` on `add` and on `get`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am required to have a HashMap<Long, Object> and a TreeMap<Integer, Object>

Comment: then I think the best option is to check map.contains(number) || map.contains((long)number) in your while loop

Comment: I attempted this but received a class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a data type from an Object by using `.getClass()` and check if it is an integer or a long.

Unless you are doing something very big and you are trying to conserve data, you should cast all the integers to longs when adding them to the map.  Remember, an integer can be a long, but a long can **not** be an integer unless the long is within the integer's max size.

Comment: A `long` _can be_ an `int` as long as it's `|x| <= Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I will definitely do the `.getClass()` and check for the data type.  But how would I get the data type from the map's key?

Alas, I wish I could use a long for everything, but the requirements of the program do not allow for that.

Comment: @Tieseven you could use Object instead of Integer or Long in your map.  When you get the key you can loop through the list and check if the data type for the key being looped is the same as the one being searched.  Then you can cast it to the one being searched and check if it is equal.  You can make that your own 'get()' method for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes of course.  I will edit my post to mention that.

Comment: @Reaper Unfortunately the requirements for the map are set in stone.  Really, I would just like some way to get the data type of a map, but AbstractMap has no such method I could find and I can't figure out another way to get that information.

Comment: @Tieseven So if I understand correctly, you have to create a program using two data types in one map? If you could please explain what you need in a edit or something so I can devise a solution to properly solve your problem.

Comment: I can update a little later tonight.  Thank you for your help.  I also realized I made a typo in my response above.  I need to get the data type of the key of a map that is passed in as a parameter.  Don't know if that helps.  Will update the post later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to change your `while` statement:

```
while (map.containsKey(number) || map.containsKey((long) number))
```

Since the keys might be Integers or might be Longs, you might as well check if either type of key is present.

**Update:**  The [contract for the containsKey method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) states that it may throw a ClassCastException "if the key is of an inappropriate type for this map."  So my answer is not viable.

Comment: I recieve this error when attempting this method.  

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: An exception has a stack trace.  On what line of code is that exception occurring?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure,  but it looks like it's when the tree map calls containsKey()... TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java:232) => TreeMap.getEntry (TreeMap.java:352) => Long.compareTo(Long.java:54)

Comment: My mistake.  The contract for the containsKey method states that it might throw a ClassCastException "if the key is of an inappropriate type for this map."  So my approach is not valid.

Comment: I appreciate the help regardless.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Long key : map.keySet()) {
     // check if int i == (int) (long) key;
}
```